# Posh doesnt recognize LasWriteTime change?

Tags: powershell

I was in the middle of trying to help another user that asked a question kind of similair to this but, I guess I just confused myself.

Theoretically, it seems like the below code works (well at least in my head), but it doesnt stop even after the conditions are met; both for the `while`, and `if`.

```
$Dire = Get-Item -Path C:\users\Abraham\Desktop | Select-Object -ExpandProperty LastWriteTime
$change = $Dire.AddSeconds(-30)

do{
Start-Sleep 3
(Get-ChildItem -Path C:\users\Abraham\Desktop ).Refresh()
    if($change -gt $Dire){
        "It changed";break} else {
        "No Change"}
        } Until($Dire -le $change)
```

I can stop the code, and run both the variables `$Dire`, and `$Change`, and they both will show changed.

Pretty simple concept: continue looping untill `$Dire` is less than or equal to `$change`. In other words, stop if the folder has been modified.

Am I stupid? What am I missing/misunderstanding? lol

EDIT: NVM, figured it out. Didn't realize that the condition will never be met as long as `$change` was outside of my loop, and it was never actually evaluating it. So no matter what, `$Change` was always still less than `$dire`.

```
$Dire = Get-Item -Path C:\users\Abraham\Desktop | Select-Object -ExpandProperty LastWriteTime


do{
$change = (Get-Item -Path C:\users\Abraham\Desktop | Select-Object -ExpandProperty LastWriteTime).AddSeconds(-10)
Start-Sleep 3
(Get-ChildItem -Path C:\users\Abraham\Desktop ).Refresh()
    if($change -gt $Dire){
        "It changed";break} else {
        "No Change"}
        } Until($Dire -le $change)
```

Comment: Will delete this in 30 mins just to so people can see this.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna check if a Folder / File has changed I would do something like this:

```
$current=(gi C:\users\Abraham\Desktop).LastWriteTime

while((gi C:\users\Abraham\Desktop).LastWriteTime -le $current)
{
    sleep 3
    "No Change"
}
```